# Get Correct Relative Path in Delphi

Tags: delphi, path, relative-path

I am writing with Delphi 2009 a little app to edit HTML files. With

```
HypRef := '../../photos/myjpg.jpg'   
If FileExists(ExpandFileName(HypRef)) then ...
```

I can find out, whether the file exists or not. Is there a function to find out the correct relative path, if FileExists gives a negative answer?

Comment: I don't really understand your question? FileExists tells you if the file is there or not. What do you expect to happen if it's not there? Do you want to search for it?

Comment: Yes, I want to do a quick search. Something like SearchTreeForFile, but including the given directory ('photos').

Answer (score 10):

I'm presuming you mean relative to the directory of the main HTML document. You can call SetCurrentDir() to the directory containing the main HTML document, or you can simply prepend that path to the relative one.

```
if FileExists(ExtractFilePath(MainDocument) + HypRef) then...
```

You really don't **need** to call ExpandFileName() since the OS will properly resolve the '..' and '.' pieces. However, if you intend to use the path for identity then they should all be cannonicalized using ExpandFileName().